# Endless loop with an observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have the following function attached to a button.

```
    saveComment(): void {
        this.firestore.getNotes(this.activeSiteService.activeCase).subscribe(
            notes => {
                const latestNote = notes.pop();
                if (typeof latestNote != undefined) {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                    // @ts-ignore
                    latestNote.comment = this.comment;
                    console.log(this.comment);
                    console.log(this.activeSiteService.activeCase);
                    this.firestore.addNote(latestNote as Note, this.activeSiteService.activeCase);
                }
            },
        );
    }
```

The firestore.getNotes and the firestore.addNote are just API calls to Firebase.

This block of code is running infinitely for some reason. Any idea why and how it can be resolved?

Comment: I'm not sure of the solution, but I see the reason for the infinite execution.  You're adding a note, which causes the subscription to fire because there's a new note, which adds a new note... etc.

Comment: @user2740650 got it right, I think if you limit the subscription to 1 it should work: `getNotes(...).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...`

Comment: @Ozan that fixed it.